# Matplotlib basemap drawcounties doesn't work

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Pretty much what the title says. My drawcounties command is just being ignored with no errors. Does it only plot on certain projections? The documentation doesn't say so.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap, shiftgrid
import scipy

def BasemapParameters():
    """
    Sets up basemap.
    """
    m = Basemap(projection='mill', llcrnrlon = 230, llcrnrlat = 27,
                                   urcrnrlat = 45, urcrnrlon = 261,
                                   area_thresh = 1000., resolution='i')
    m.drawcounties(linewidth=0.5)
    m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.7)
    m.drawcountries(linewidth=0.5)
    m.drawstates(linewidth=0.5)
    m.drawmapboundary(linewidth=0.7)

def SavePlot(lvl,parameter,region,hour,padding):
    """
    Saves figure to file with given properties
    """
    plt.savefig('{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}.png'.format(lvl,parameter,region,hour),bbox_inches='tight',pad_inches = padding)
    plt.close("all")
    print('  "{0}_{1}_{2}_{3}.png" created.'.format(lvl,parameter,region,hour))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
BasemapParameters()
SavePlot('sfc','3hrpcp','sw','000',.07)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Drawcounties ... I read that drawcount**r**ies ... apologies, I accidentally flagged this before I read it properly.  You may want to take out the drawcountries command so others don't make the same mistake :/

Answer (score 1):

drawcoastlines() is plotting polygons with white faces, so that is going on top of the county lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting zorder = 20 (or something high) in drawcounties to put the county lines on top of the countries. Also see https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/324.